# How to debug AJAX POST request that redirects?

Tags: javascript, ajax, debugging

I am trying to debug a problem with SugarCRM.

When I click the next page button to browse the records of one of my extensions, it shows a blank page with this error message `Bad data passed in; Return to Home`

My searches online has resulted in now help for this issue so far as it seems many things can cause the issue.

So I would now like to somehow monitor the data that is being sent when I click that button.  It appears to use AJAX to send some data but it immediately redirects so I am not able to see what data was sent.

Can someone tell me how to monitor and see the posted data before a redirect happens?

Comment: Your best bet is to track down the javascript that the click or submit is calling, and drop a breakpoint in it. What browser are you using?

Comment: You can start using [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/), if you're not already doing so. It's a pretty useful tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Firebug extension with Firefox and activate the Network tab to see every network call.

The tricky part is to activate the button "Persists" in order to prevent to clean the log when a redirection or a user action changes the URL.

[image: Example Persists button location]